# How to get time(Hours/Minute) spent per interval using Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba

Please help to modify the below macro code. I am trying to create a macro code that will get the time spent per interval based on the StartTime and EndTime.

Ex: StartTime-7:10PM EndTime-9:45PM
For 1hour interval time spent will be:
7:00-(50mins)
8:00-(1hr)
9:00-(45mins)

The below code is working for 1 hour interval however if I change the interval to 50mins or 30mins it's not working.

```
Private wb As Workbook
Private ws As Worksheet
Private srchRng As Range

Public Function GetCurrentHourInterval(ByVal startTime As Date) As Date
    GetCurrentHourInterval = TimeSerial(Hour(startTime), 0, 0)
End Function

'Public Sub GetHoursSpentPerInterval(ByVal startTime As Date, ByVal endtime As Date)
Public Sub GetHoursSpentPerInterval()
   Set wb = Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name)
   Set ws = wb.Sheets("Summary")
   Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Raw Data")
   
   Dim startTime As Date
   Dim endTime As Date
   Dim currentInterval As Date
   Dim lRow As Integer
   Dim agntSel, statSel As String
   
ws.Select
agntSel = Range("D4").Value
statSel = Range("D3").Value
Range("I6").Value = statSel
Range("I7:I54").Select
Selection.ClearContents

Range("J8").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("H8").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H8:H54")
    Range("H8:H54").Select
    
Selection.Copy
    Range("H8").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
Range("A1").Select

ws2.Select
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For a = 2 To lRow

   startTime = Range("M" & a).Value
   endTime = Range("N" & a).Value
   
   currentInterval = GetCurrentHourInterval(startTime)
   
   If agntSel = Range("A" & a).Value And statSel = Range("B" & a).Value Then

   Dim hourLoop As Integer

   For hourLoop = Hour(currentInterval) To Hour(endTime)
      If currentInterval <= TimeValue(startTime) Then
         Set srchRng = ws.Range("H7:H30").Find(what:=currentInterval)
         
         'GET NEXT INTERVAL FROM INTERVAL COLUMN B
         Dim nextInterval As Date
         nextInterval = currentInterval + TimeValue("1:0:0")
         
         If Hour(startTime) = Hour(endTime) Then
            srchRng.Offset(0, 1).Value = TimeSerial(0, Minute(startTime), Second(startTime))
            Exit For
         Else
            srchRng.Offset(0, 1).Value = nextInterval - TimeValue(startTime)
         End If
         
         If Hour(nextInterval) = Hour(endTime) Then
            startTime = endTime
         Else
            startTime = DateValue(startTime) + nextInterval
         End If
         
         currentInterval = GetCurrentHourInterval(startTime)
      End If
   Next
   End If
Next
  ws.Select
   Set srchRng = Nothing
   Set ws = Nothing
   Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: not sure I follow what this code is trying to do to be honest.  Your for loop seems to only output to `srchRng.Offset(0, 1)` and as far as I can see doesn't seem to reference that value.  However, I think i would look at what's happening here `For hourLoop = Hour(currentInterval) To Hour(endTime)`  if you step through the code ([link](https://riptutorial.com/excel-vba/example/8020/debugger-locals-window) or more detailed ([link](https://madschedules.com/microsoft-project-vba-locals-window/)) you should be able to see what is happening when you use less than an one hour interval

Comment: Here are the screenshot of Raw Data and Summary Output. It might help for understanding. Raw Data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UQhlK4C94eVYz-TGCeGCdFWfUL_u0Ilp/view?usp=sharing Summary Output: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Vk6M7ixq0CxFZGKoij4OXut8Oz1oHHcx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: so you want to input a time interval and get the list of times in that day based on each interval step?  could you do something like:  `Range("A1") = midNight` then `Range("A2") = A1 + intervalFraction` where `intervalFraction = interval / 24`.  i know it doesn't fix the above if but i think it will be a simplier code to get that output

Comment: Actually, I want to get the time spent per interval based on the StartTime and EndTime. For example, StartTime-7:10PM EndTime-9:45PM For 1hour interval time spent will be: 7:00-(50mins) 8:00-(1hr) 9:00-(45mins). The code is working for 1hour interval. However, if it changes to 50 or 30 minutes it's not working. But the output should be: For 30mins interval time spent will be: 7:00-(20mins) 7:30-(30mins) 8:00-(30mins) 8:30-(30mins) 9:00-(30mins) 9:30-(15mins).

Comment: in which case i would look at that for loop and step through the code as I said

Comment: I run the code step by step and the error is coming from this line: See screenshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kpCfDIelkoO_X227mcBjIOq9CeiQSKkB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: can you give some context of what issue you're seeing at this line?

Comment: Object Variable or With block variable not set

Comment: ok and if you hover over the three parts of that line `srchRng.Offset(0, 1).Value`, `nextInterval`,  `TimeValue(startTime)` it should give you a box that shows what each one equates to.  Also look at the locals window to make sure that all those variables have a value